# formatting string on the same line

Tags: python, string, formatting

if i have a procedure such as:

```
   def P(x):
      # x is an integer
      print str(x)
```

and i want to have an output such as:

```
    >>> You chose the number: X
```

where X is the result printed inside procedure P.
How can I do that without changing the procedure?

If I do like this:

```
  print 'You chose the number: '
  P(x)
```

I'll get

```
 You chose the number: 
 X
```

How can I get them in the same line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `trailing` comma after the first print statement, to print the next statement in the same line: -

```
print 'You chose the number: ',
P(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

try string formatting:

```
 print 'You chose the number: {0}'.format(P(x))
```

and instead of printing from the function use `return`:

```
   def P(x):
      return str(x)
```

Comment: OP does not want to change the procedure P(x)

Comment: @RohitJain I think I missed that part, but it's a good practice to `return` values from function instead of printing inside it.

Comment: Yeah, that is of course a better option in this case, specially when OP is doing nothing but printing the string representation of the value passed.

Answer (score 1):

What about any of

```
P('You chose the number: ' + str(x))
P('You chose the number: {0}'.format(x))
P('You chose the number: %s' % x)
```

? You don't have to change `P()` as other answers suggest.